# Delete circle when clicked on it - Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would want to be able to click a point and make it go away while giving the R value as well (when the remove radio button is toggled). The else if is the part that should be changed. It currently deletes the last value created and but not the one i'm clicking on. Also, the circle is not deleted, everything is (you don't need to read all of the code but running it might be helpful to understand).

NOTE: It is important that it is the circle that is clicked and not the coordinate since it is too small. It is also important that the circle disappears and not only the value on the dataset.

I have the following code:

```js
// Width and height of svg
var w = 600;
var h = 400;
var padding = 15;

var xmin = -50;
var xmax = 50;
var ymin = -30;
var ymax = 30;

var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

var dataset = [];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([xmin, xmax])
  .range([padding, w - padding]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([ymax, ymin])
  .range([padding, h - padding]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h / 2 + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickValues([-40, -20, 20, 40]));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + ",0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickValues([30, 20, 10, -10, -20, -30]));

svg.on("click", function() {
  if (button1.checked) {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log(coords);
    
    dataset.push({
      x: coords[0],
      y: coords[1]
    });
    
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", coords[0])
      .attr("cy", coords[1])
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("fill", 'red');

    d3.select("#correlation")
      .text(correlation(dataset));
  } else if (button2.checked) {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log(coords);
    
    var index = dataset.indexOf(coords);
    
    if (index > -1) {
      dataset.splice(index, 1);
    }
    
    d3.select("#correlation")
      .text(correlation(dataset));
  }
});

function correlation(dataset) {
  if (dataset.length < 2) {
    return "We need at least two points.";
  } else {
    var top = 0;
    var bottom1 = 0;
    var bottom2 = 0;
    
    var meanx = d3.mean(dataset, function(d) {
      return xScale.invert(d.x);
    });
    
    var meany = d3.mean(dataset, function(d) {
      return yScale.invert(d.y);
    });
    
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      var x = xScale.invert(dataset[i].x);
      var y = yScale.invert(dataset[i].y);
      top += (x - meanx) * (y - meany);
      bottom1 += Math.pow(x - meanx, 2);
      bottom2 += Math.pow(y - meany, 2);
    }
    
    return "r: " + (top / (Math.sqrt(bottom1) * Math.sqrt(bottom2))).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 600px">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="1" id="button1">Add points</input>
    <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="2" id="button2">Remove points</input>
  </form>

  <h3 id="correlation">Two points are needed to calculate r.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to give the circles an id and attach a `click` handler, on click remove the element with the given id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
else if (button2.checked) {
  var coords = d3.mouse(this);
  var index = dataset.indexOf(coords);
  if (index > -1) {
    dataset.splice(index, 1);
  }
  d3.select("#correlation").text(correlation(dataset));
}
```

`coords` in your case is an array of 2 elements, x and y, it looks like this `[200, 50]` while your `dataset` is an array of objects that looks like this `[{x: 200, y: 50}]` so `var index = dataset.indexOf(coords);` will obviously not work since you are looking for an array inside of an array of objects.

You need to do something like this:

```
else if (button2.checked)   {
  var coords = d3.mouse(this);
  var index = dataset.indexOf(coords);

  var index = dataset.findIndex(function(element) {
    return element.x === coords[0] && element.y === coords[1];
  });
  console.log('index', index);

  if (index > -1) {
    dataset.splice(index, 1);
  }
  d3.select("#correlation").text(correlation(dataset));
}
```

Be careful because your y is very precise(it looks like '50.2455') meaning that you must click that circle in the very center in order to trigger it. Maybe you can improve this a bit.

**UPDATE**

Best way would be to trigger the event whenever you click on the area of the dot. So since the dot is 8px x 8px you can add and substract 4px x 2 on both axis. This way the remove will trigger no matter on what part of the dot you click.

```
else if (button2.checked)   {
  var coords = d3.mouse(this);
  var index = dataset.indexOf(coords);
  console.log(coords);
  console.log(dataset);

  var index = dataset.findIndex(function(element) {
    return element.x >= coords[0] - 4 && element.x <= coords[0] + 4 && element.y >= coords[1] - 4 && element.y <= coords[1] + 4;
  });
  console.log('index', index);

  if (index > -1) {
    dataset.splice(index, 1);
  }
  d3.select("#correlation").text(correlation(dataset));
  }
})
```

**UPDATE**

This includes the removal of the dot from the view.

```
else if (button2.checked) {
  var coords = d3.mouse(this);
  var elX = null;
  var elY = null;

  var index = dataset.findIndex(function (element) {
    if (element.x >= coords[0] - 4 && element.x <= coords[0] + 4 && element.y >= coords[1] - 4 && element.y <= coords[1] + 4) {
      elX = element.x;
      elY = element.y;
    }
    return element.x >= coords[0] - 4 && element.x <= coords[0] + 4 && element.y >= coords[1] - 4 && element.y <= coords[1] + 4;
  });

  if (index > -1) {
    dataset.splice(index, 1);
    var d = document.querySelector('[cx="' + elX + '"][cy="' + elY + '"]');
    d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
  }
  d3.select("#correlation").text(correlation(dataset));
}
```

Comment: Maybe create an area the size of the dot? Also, the circle isn't deleted, only the value in dataset. I need the image to be removed

Comment: Can you make your `y` look like your `x`? It seems that `x` shows as `200` while `y` looks like `200.1255`.

Comment: The specific value of x and y will depend on where the point is added, so not really...

Comment: It works way better! However the circles still do not disappear